# Proving that set with inequality is a submanifold

Tags: real-analysis, integration, manifolds, submanifold

I want to show that $M=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x-y^2=z^2+4,|x|<10\}$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The first condition is easy to fulfill with $f(x,y,z):=x-y^2-z^2-4$ and $\{f=0\}$ but how can I treat the second condition?

Comment: $M$ is by definition in $U$, so $M\cap U =M$ and $M\cap U= \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|f(x,y,z):=x-y^2-z^2-4=0\}$ is incorrect.

Comment: For your integral, what do you think is wrong?